# QueryException: List has no rows for assignment in test class

Tags: unit-test, deployment, error

I have included the following code and dependencies (fields) in my change set and I'm encountering the following error:

> LeadCreateOppTrigger.LeadCreateOppTrigger(), Details:
>   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>   Class.LeadCreateOppTrigger.LeadCreateOppTrigger: line 45, column 1

It's important to mention this test class works and causes 95% code coverage for the Trigger it is meant to address in testing.

Please advise on how this would be remedied:

(Line 45 is indicated below)

```
@isTest
private class LeadCreateOppTrigger {

 public TestMethod static void LeadCreateOppTrigger() {

    Lead myLead = new Lead ( //Address = '123 Main St. Anywhere USA',
                            LastName = 'Doe',
                            FirstName = 'John',
                            Company = 'AnyCompany',
                            Desired_City1__c = 'AnyCity1',
                            Desired_City2__c = 'AnyCity2',
                            Desired_City3__c = 'AnyCity3',
                            Desired_County1__c = 'AnyCounty1',
                            Desired_County2__c = 'AnyCounty2',
                            Desired_Property_Description__c = 'Any Description',
                            Desired_State1__c = 'AnyState1',
                            Desired_State2__c = 'AnyState2',
                            Desired_State3__c = 'AnyState3',
                            Pre_Approval_Amount__c = 12345.00,
                            Pre_Approval_Granted__c = true,
                            Salutation__c = 'Mr.');

    insert myLead;

    myLead.Real_Estate_Agent_Assigned__c = true;
    update myLead;

    //Opportunity[] myOpp = new Opportunity[1];
    /*Line 45*/ Opportunity myOpp = [SELECT
                            Desired_City1__c,
                            Desired_City2__c,
                            Desired_City3__c,
                            Desired_County1__c,
                            Desired_County2__c,
                            Desired_Property_Description__c,
                            Desired_State1__c,
                            Desired_State2__c,
                            Desired_State3__c,
                            Lead_Id__c,
                            Pre_Approval_Amount__c,
                            Pre_Approval_Granted__c,
                            Real_Estate_Agent_Assigned__c,
                            Salutation__c
                        FROM Opportunity WHERE Lead_Id__c =: myLead.Id LIMIT 1];

        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_City1__c, 'AnyCity1');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_City2__c, 'AnyCity2');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_City3__c, 'AnyCity3');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_County1__c, 'AnyCounty1');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_County2__c, 'AnyCounty2');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_Property_Description__c, 'Any Description');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_State1__c, 'AnyState1');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_State2__c, 'AnyState2');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Desired_State3__c, 'AnyState3');
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Lead_Id__c, String.valueOf(myLead.Id));
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Pre_Approval_Amount__c, 12345.00);
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Pre_Approval_Granted__c, true);
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Real_Estate_Agent_Assigned__c, true);     
        System.assertEquals(myOpp.Salutation__c, 'Mr.');
    } // End TestTriggerCreatemyOpp()
} // End Lead_CreatemyOpp_Trigger_Test
```

Comment: Where do you create the `Opportunity` in the test? How the heck does this pass in the lower environment?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - This, and other approaches - like declaring and creating the Opportunity object first, have failed as well.

Comment: You need to insert it into the database so the query can find it... you didn't answer if it passes in the source org.

Comment: The Trigger (being tested by this class) creates the Opportunity from the Lead on insert and update.  The data (Oppty) is available following insert/update, and both compiles and runs as a test class for the Trigger it is meant to test in the sandbox successfully (95% coverage).  This was what I explained at the beginning of my post - my apologies if that was not clear.

Comment: Just a couple notes on best practice in regards to assertions, take a look at the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals) on `system.assertEquals`. The parameter order is `(expected, actual, message)`. Make sure you put your expected value first, and you should try to add helpful messages where possible (everywhere hopefully).

Comment: Also you would need to post your trigger code for us to really understand. Are you certain you did not forget any package components? For instance, forgetting the trigger would do it in this case.

Comment: Thanks Adrian - all good points.  I'm going to create a new deployment package and try once again.  If this is not successful I will post the Trigger code as well.

Comment: another useful point - code that tests triggers should do bulk inserts and updates - verifies that your trigger wasn't coded for a single record - why? because your trigger will get executed anytime a  mass update on lead (list views) or data loader operation occurs

Comment: I successfully deployed to prod after creating a new outbound change set that included: trigger; test class; dependent fields; dependent page layouts while using appropriate API versions.  This is exactly what I followed when I first created a change set and received failures on validating the incoming change set.  I'm scratching my head here as to why this works but did not before and also why it passed in the sandbox but failed earlier validation in  the prod instance.  In any case - problem solved.  Thanks Adrian Larson.  I also appreciate input from crop1645.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of your test, your trigger is not working because the opportunity is not being created (expected behavior). The query to retrieve it is not returning any result. Independently from that, if you want to avoid that `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment` exception, you can simply change your myOpp variable for a list.

```
List<Opportunity> myOpp = [SELECT
                        Desired_City1__c,
                        Desired_City2__c,
                        Desired_City3__c,
                        Desired_County1__c,
                        Desired_County2__c,
                        Desired_Property_Description__c,
                        Desired_State1__c,
                        Desired_State2__c,
                        Desired_State3__c,
                        Lead_Id__c,
                        Pre_Approval_Amount__c,
                        Pre_Approval_Granted__c,
                        Real_Estate_Agent_Assigned__c,
                        Salutation__c
                    FROM Opportunity WHERE Lead_Id__c =: myLead.Id LIMIT 1];
```

The exception should not be thrown, however you'll have to double check the trigger's code if the test does not pass.